# Can't install Script on Atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor

Just installed Atom and tried to install Script to run my code (Windows user)

I tried from the [website](https://atom.io/packages/script) but when clicking Install, it says `Launching Atom... If nothing happens, download Atom and try again.` And nothing happens

Also tried from Atom itself but can't find Script. A list of packages appears but no Script.

Finally, I tried `apm install script` from the command prompt. I'm getting `Installing script to C:\Users\Administartor\.atom\packages`, waiting for few minutes but... Nothing.

UPDATE: Closed and re-opened Atom. Now getting the following:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atom wasn't set as the default program to open atom:// links.

Once I activated it from the Settings -> URI Handling I could install Script from the website

[image]

Comment: I have this problem too. I have set the URI handler, but still cannot install script. I click on the "Install" button on https://atom.io/packages/script, which opens atom. However, install fails. I get the message "Failed to load script - try again later." I have tried later (on different days and different times), but no success.